# clang++ (version 3.3) lacks headers

Tags: c++, clang

This seems odd. Take a simple C++ program

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    std::cout << "Square root of 9 is " << sqrt(9) << std::endl;

}
```

which passes fine with `g++` (4.8) but fails to compile with `clang++` (3.3).

```
edd@don:/tmp$ g++ -o cmath cmath.cpp 
edd@don:/tmp$ ./cmath 
Square root of 9 is 3
edd@don:/tmp$ clang++ -o cmath cmath.cpp 
In file included from cmath.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/cmath:41:10: \
       fatal error: 
      'bits/c++config.h' file not found
#include <bits/c++config.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
edd@don:/tmp$
```

I suspect I am missing something blatantly obvious.

And I do have the relevant `-dev` package:

```
edd@don:/tmp$ COLUMNS=72 dpkg -l | grep "clang\|llvm"
ii  clang-3.3      1:3.3-5ubunt i386         C, C++ and Objective-C compiler (
ii  libclang-commo 1:3.3-5ubunt i386         clang library - Common developmen
ii  libclang-commo 1:3.2repack- i386         clang library - Common developmen
ii  libclang1      1:3.2repack- i386         clang library
ii  libclang1-3.3  1:3.3-5ubunt i386         clang library
ii  libllvm3.1:i38 3.1-2ubuntu2 i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM),
ii  libllvm3.2:i38 1:3.2repack- i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM),
ii  libllvm3.3:i38 1:3.3-5ubunt i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM),
ii  llvm-3.3       1:3.3-5ubunt i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM)
ii  llvm-3.3-dev   1:3.3-5ubunt i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM),
ii  llvm-3.3-runti 1:3.3-5ubunt i386         Low-Level Virtual Machine (LLVM),
edd@don:/tmp$
```

*Edit:* I had failed to check the Bug Tracking System, this is in [in fact known at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-3.3/+bug/1243725).

*Edit 2:*  In Ubuntu 16.10, it finally works:

```
edd@max:~/src/progs/C++(master)$ clang++ -o cmath cmath.cpp 
edd@max:~/src/progs/C++(master)$ ./cmath 
Square root of 9 is 3
edd@max:~/src/progs/C++(master)$
```

using `clang++` version 3.8.1.

Comment: I see bug report WON'T FIXED, 13.10 isn't supported anymore, and 3.3 is removed in 15.04. So I voted to close it.

Comment: @Sneetsher: You do understand that I filed this nearly two years ago _when that distribution version and package were current_?

Comment: Yeah, I do. I just see the question get aged away. I don't any one is going to answer. But if want, you can write one mention the workaround from the bug report that add `-i /path-to-std-headers`. That will any coming later here. 7 votes seem have some attraction. :)

Comment: For what it is worth this still does not build (by default) in 2016 under 16.04.  Sad.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: This is now fixed. Please close the question such that it gets taken off the unanswered list:
`  
    $ clang++ -o cmath cmath.cpp  
    $ ./cmath  
    Square root of 9 is 3  
    $ clang++ --version  
    clang version 3.8.1-12ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)  
    Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu  
    Thread model: posix  
    InstalledDir: /usr/bin  
    $ cat /etc/issue  
    Ubuntu 16.10 \n \l
`

Comment: @KimPhillips Sure, so why didn't you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It (at last) works in Ubuntu 16.10:

```
edd@max:~/src/progs/C++(master)$ cat cmath.cpp 

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    std::cout << "Square root of 9 is " << sqrt(9) << std::endl;

}
edd@max:~/src/progs/C++(master)$ clang++ -o cmath cmath.cpp 
edd@max:~/src/progs/C++(master)$ ./cmath 
Square root of 9 is 3
edd@max:~/src/progs/C++(master)$
```